# What is the effecient way of returning a promise in for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a function that return a promise after a for-loop in javascript, and since i am new to promise and async-await i was wondering if this the efficient way of returning a promise in iteration process. Here is the snippet

```
function addImagesToCanvas(urls){

    return new Promise(resolve => {

       for(url of urls){

          loadImage(url).then(img_element =>{

              addImageToCanvas(img_element);
          });
       }

       resolve();
    });

}

function displayCanvas(){

      $.ajax({
             ....
             success: function(response){

                   urls = JSON.Parse(response);
                   addImagesToCanvas(urls).then(() => {

                        //..Do something
                   });

             }
      });

}

Is there a way of re-writting the above code with **async/await** ? Thanks for the comments
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: have you tried chaining the promises using defer ? https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: @sabkaraja - There's no mention of jQuery above, and although jQuery's `Deferred`s are (now) *thenable*, they aren't *promises*.

Comment: he's using $.ajax -- hence I mentioned jquery. rest I agree with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not. Your code doesn't wait for the promises within the loop to resolve.

If you want to wait for them *in series* (one after another, each waiting for the previous one), then since you mentioned using an `async` function and `await`, you just write it in standard logical flow, awaiting each promise:

```
async function addImagesToCanvas(urls){
    for (url of urls) {
       const img_element = await loadImage(url);
       addImageToCanvas(img_element);
    }
}
```

or of course:

```
async function addImagesToCanvas(urls){
    for (url of urls) {
       addImageToCanvas(await loadImage(url));
    }
}
```

If you want to let them all process in parallel and wait for the result, use `map` to get an aaray of the promises and return the promise created by `Promise.all` and return its promise:

```
function addImagesToCanvas(urls){
    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => loadImage(url).then(addImageToCanvas)));
}
```

Or alternately:

```
function addImagesToCanvas(urls){
    return Promise.all(urls.map(async (url) => {
        addImageToCanvas(await loadImage(url);
    }));
}
```

No need for the function itself to be `async`, since it can directly return the promise from `Promise.all`.

---

Side note: Your code seems to be falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare `url`. For instance, in the first code block above:

```
async function addImagesToCanvas(urls){
    for (const url of urls) {
//       ^^^^^----------------------------------------- const or let (or even var, but...I wouldn't)
       const img_element = await loadImage(url);
       addImageToCanvas(img_element);
    }
}
```